# cleartool: Error: Checkout disallowed for element "."

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I got the error while trying to check out the "`.`" directory in clearcase.

FYI:

1. view is syncronized with the stream config and all components are modifiable.
2. The stream has foundation baselines as well as recommended baselines.
3. The vob is the component of ucm pvob.

   ```
   cleartool co -nc "."
   cleartool: Error: Checkout disallowed for element ".": 
     the component containing the element or the current stream is read-only 
     in this project, or the stream lacks foundation baselines.
   cleartool: Error: Unable to check out ".".
   ```

How would you troubleshoot this error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems '`.`' represents the root folder of the vob here.

> The vob is the component of ucm pvob.

**Make sure you don't checkout a pvob**.
You need to checkout the vob of the component (associated to a pvob), not a pvob.

I have seen this message when trying to checkout an element within `aVob/lost+found` folder.
If that is the case, you need to not select that '`lost+found`' directory in the config spec.

```
element /aVob/lost+found -none
```

Otherwise:

- double-check your component is indeed writable in the project (properties on the project)
- make sure your stream knows about that

  ```
  cleartool chstream -generate stream:a_stream@\a_pvob
  ```
- make sure the config spec of your view is in sync with the Stream configuration

  ```
  cd /path/to/your/view
  cleartool setcs -stream
  ```

Comment: what I am trying to do here is add some files in the component vob. The vob doesn't contain anything in present situation so I am trying to check out the . directory in order to make some elements and add them and it has nothing to do with lost+found since nothing is checked out and removed. I don't understand this "element /aVob/lost+found -none."

Comment: @user2370590 what is the exact full path you are in, when you do a checkout '.'?

Comment: @user2370590 I also edited my answer to comment on the fact you wouldn't checkout a pvob, only an UCM vob (associated to a pvob).

Comment: @user2370590 finally, I assume the vob itself is the component (ie the component root folder isn't a subfolder of the vob, but rather the vob itself).

Comment: Hyperlinks: AdminVOB <- vob:/vobs/zebra1. Above error occured when I cd /vobs/zebra1 and run the command: the cleartool co -nc .

Comment: @user2370590 what does `cleartool lsvob /vobs/project1` returns? if you see "`(ucmpvob)`", this isn't good.

Comment: /vobs/zebra1       /net/att1/exports/att1_fs2/vob_store/tcc/zebra1.vbs public
this is not a ucm pvob.

Comment: @user2370590 can you follow http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21147165, and make sure that `project1` is actually a vob component?